# Row num is not working for duplicate columns while pagination

Tags: oracle, pagination

Code is written below, multiple nested query:

```
 select *
        from
      (select employee_id,employee_id
         from employees) a
       where rownum <= 5
      )
       where rnum >= 10
```

If i give duplicate columns in the select its giving "column ambiguously defined" error.

Comment: Please formulate your question and provide more details. What exactly "not working"? How pagination performed?

Comment: If i give duplicate columns in the select its giving column ambiguously defined error..select *
        from
      (select a.*,Rownum rnum
         from
      (select employee_id,employee_id
         from employees) a
       where rownum <= 5
      )
       where rnum >= 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when you give `a.*` it means you are trying to refer two columns with same name in a table which is not permitted.The column names in a table are unique
>
> So `select employee_id,employee_id from employees` is not a problem
>
> but
>
> `select a.* from (select employee_id,employee_id from employees)a` is a problem
>
> [the sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/3245)

Also if you want records from 10 to 15 in your query then use like the below

```
  select * from 
     (select a.*,Rownum rnum from 
     (select employee_id as emp_id1,employee_id as emp_id2 
         from employees order by 1) 
      a where rownum <= 15 ) where rnum >= 10
```

**EDIT1:-** If duplicate column is required use like the below

```
  with emp1 as (select employee_id from employees),
  emp2 as (select * from 
          (select a.*,rownum rnum from emp1 a order by 1)   
           where rownum <=15)
  select b.*,c.*
  from emp1 b,emp2 c
  where b.employee_id=c.employee_id
  and c.rnum >=10
```

Comment: Yes you are correct but i need achieve this without giving alias to duplicate columns,is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need to do like that

Comment: I cant give alias for duplicate columns,I need with the same name as column appears in db.

Comment: SQL> emp1 as (select employee_id from emp),
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "emp1 as (s..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL>   emp2 as (select * from
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "emp2 as (s..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL>           (select a.*,rownum rnum from emp1 a order by 1)
  2             where rownum <=15)
  3    select b.*,c.*
  4    from emp1 b,emp2 c
  5    where b.employee_id=c.employee_id
  6    and c.rnum >=10;
          (select a.*,rownum rnum from emp1 a order by 1)
                                              *
ERROR at line 1:
**ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis**

Answer (score 3):

> employee_id,employee_id, rownum rnum

- Firstly, your query is incorrect since you have **ambiguously defined the columns**. It will throw `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`.

You must use proper **ALIAS** to avoid the error. For example,

```
SELECT departments.department_id AS "dept_id", 
        employees.department_id  AS "emp_Dept_id" 
FROM...
```

- Secondly, it is not at all a pagination query. Since you are alwyas going to pick random rows as there is no **ORDER BY** clause. You are not ordering the rows.

> where rownum <= 5
>
> where rnum >= 10

- At last, *how on earth could you try to fetch the rows beyond 10 when you have fetched ONLY 5 rows in the inner query?* It will **ALWAYS return zero rows**.

The correct way of **paging through data** is:

```
SQL> SELECT empno
  2  FROM   (SELECT empno, rownum AS rnum
  3          FROM   (SELECT empno
  4                  FROM   emp
  5                  ORDER BY sal)
  6          WHERE rownum <= 8)
  7  WHERE  rnum >= 5;

     EMPNO
----------
      7654
      7934
      7844
      7499

SQL>
```

Comment: Ok , but the thing is if I have two same columns from different tables in the select(like departments.department_id,employees.department_id) it will throw the same error

Comment: Use proper `alias`. Read the documentation about how to use `alias` for column names. For example, `SELECT departments.department_id deptid, employees.department_id emp_dept_id...`

Comment: Sine the departments.department_id equals the employees.department_id, why are you returning both of them?

Comment: Or if is there any other way to fetch the limited number of records from DB please mention it.